# Work about Earth or humanity being destroyed for being peaceful

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm sure it was a book, but it could have been a film, or even a video-game plot element. Apologize if I've mixed up any facts – I don't think I've come across this again in the last 20 years!

I read this "book" a long time ago, and a small part of the story refers to the Earth being visited by aliens, who (IIRC) told us that they were disappointed in how we had progressed as a species, and gave humanity the chance to repair their culture…

I believe, they left the Earth and came back after a time to be told that humanity had worked hard and had now declared a full and lasting world-peace and equality. However, the aliens wanted the opposite, they wanted us to be even more vicious to be used as soldiers or something along those lines.

I believe that they then promptly destroyed either the planet or the species!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the Twilight Zone segment [*A Small Talent for War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Small_Talent_for_War).

> The global peace agreement brings great humour to the emissary. The
>   aliens were, in fact, seeking a greater talent for war, as they had
>   genetically seeded thousands of planets to breed warriors to fight for
>   them across the galaxy. Humanity's "small talent" for war (crude
>   weapons, petty bickering over borders) is not significant enough to be
>   of any use to them. And he laughingly states that—worst of all—the
>   people of Earth long for peace. As the ambassador calls down his fleet
>   to destroy the Earth, he thanks the Security Council for an amusing
>   day and their "delightful sense of the absurd."

Comment: Vaguely related: [The Liberation of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Liberation_of_Earth)

Comment: I wasn't sure I'd find an answer, I think that 'd almost convinced myself that this was just the plot of a weird dream! I'm very grateful Valorum!

Comment: @RuneStephenson - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)