# Searching for a specific sci-fi story or episode (to help a friend who can't find it), unsure whether it's book, radio, or television

Tags: story-identification

I have a friend who has asked my help to find a sci-fi story; this would be a short story, more likely to be an episode on television. It has many similarities to Twilight Zone (any of the versions over the decades) or Amazing Stories, etc.

This story involves aliens coming to earth and telling us that we've messed up / we're doing things all wrong. They leave, and come back some time later to find that earth has become united and humans have created world peace. The ironic twist: they say that we misunderstood them - we were meant to be war-like and we weren't doing enough fighting or self-destruction.

Can anyone help me find this story? Again, my friend doesn't recall whether it was on television (he remembers it being on TV), but it could have been a radio show or a short story in a collection.

Comment: That's the Twilight Zone episode "[A Small Talent for War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Small_Talent_for_War)" as detailed in [this recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232100/work-about-earth-or-humanity-being-destroyed-for-being-peaceful).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Work about Earth or humanity being destroyed for being peaceful](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232100/work-about-earth-or-humanity-being-destroyed-for-being-peaceful)

Comment: OMG - DavidW - that's IT! That is what I've been trying to help my friend search for, for months! Thank you so much!!

Comment: VtC - poster has confirmed the correct answer exists to another question in comments.

Comment: @DavidW I recommend you provide an answer for the OP to accept as that leaves the best paper trail. As opposed to an acceptance in the comments.